# Python/Pandas - Writing empty cells to a csv file (instead of zeros)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, csv

Running Python 3.8.1, 64 bit, on Windows 10.

I have a csv file with two columns. The first column does not have numeric values on every row (=empty cells in between cells with values) and second has numeric values on every row.

```
column_1 column_2
         200
13       201
         202
         203
         204
         205
129      206
16       207
         208
```

I read the csv file (shown above) with Pandas:

```
df = pd.read_csv("old.csv")
```

I make modifications to the Pandas dataframe and write to a new csv file with Pandas without the index column.

```
df.to_csv("new.csv", sep=',', encoding='utf-8', index=False)
```

The result is a csv file that has zeros in place of the original empty cells.

```
column_1,column_2
0,200
13,201
0,202
0,203
0,204
0,205
129,206
16,207
0,208
```

My question: **how to modify my script to write empty cells instead of zeros (0) in the csv file (i.e. the rows where column_2 value is 200, 202, 203, 204, 205 and 208)?**

Comment: `I make modifications to the Pandas dataframe` do you replace missing values to `0` ? Because pandas write only `0` if exist, if missing values write no value (so get for last value `,208`)

Comment: @jezrael I am replacing every empty value to "" (empty string), and after that I print df.head(50) and **it correctly shows the dataframe with empty cells.** After that, I write the dataframe to csv and the zeros appear, which I don't want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set `0` to missing values by `Series.mask` and for integers, convert the output to [`Int64`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/integer_na.html), working in `pandas 0.24+`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'column_1': [0, 13, 0, 0, 0, 0, 129, 16, 0],
                   'column_2': [200, 201, 202, 203, 204, 205, 206, 207, 208]})
print (df)
   column_1  column_2
0         0       200
1        13       201
2         0       202
3         0       203
4         0       204
5         0       205
6       129       206
7        16       207
8         0       208

df['column_1'] = df['column_1'].mask(df['column_1'].eq(0)).astype('Int64')
print (df)
   column_1  column_2
0       NaN       200
1        13       201
2       NaN       202
3       NaN       203
4       NaN       204
5       NaN       205
6       129       206
7        16       207
8       NaN       208
```

---

```
df.to_csv("new.csv", sep=',', encoding='utf-8', index=False)

column_1,column_2
,200
13,201
,202
,203
,204
,205
129,206
16,207
,208
```

Another idea is to replace the empty strings:

```
df['column_1'] = df['column_1'].mask(df['column_1'].eq(0), '')
print (df)
  column_1  column_2
0                200
1       13       201
2                202
3                203
4                204
5                205
6      129       206
7       16       207
8                208

df.to_csv("new.csv", sep=',', encoding='utf-8', index=False)

column_1,column_2
,200
13,201
,202
,203
,204
,205
129,206
16,207
,208
```

Comment: I would like to set **empty string** to missing values, not zero. Is this possible with your suggestion?

Comment: @jeppoo1 - in my solution is converted `0` values to `NaN`s, so if written to file get emty string, for you not working?

Comment: @jeppoo1 - Added sample data, for me working perfectly.

Comment: Thank you! Your sample code is very good. I just noticed that once again, Excel is not working as expected and it adds the zeros to the empty cells... **If I open the csv in notepad or notepad++ there are empty cells as expected.** So I believe my original solution works also, I just got distracted by Excel. Very annoying, thank you Microsoft!